# Resilio sync won't start on boot

Tags: systemd

I have a problem I fail to debug, meaning I am unable to find any error message or log telling me what's wrong.

When I boot my system, resilio sync is not running:

```
$ systemctl --user status resilio-sync
● resilio-sync.service - Resilio Sync service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/resilio-sync.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: http://help.getsync.com/
```

But when I start it manually, it starts without any issues.

```
$ systemctl --user start resilio-sync
$ systemctl --user status resilio-sync
● resilio-sync.service - Resilio Sync service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/resilio-sync.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-03-27 18:33:14 CEST; 31s ago
     Docs: http://help.getsync.com/
  Process: 2553 ExecStart=/usr/bin/rslsync --config %h/.config/resilio-sync/config.json (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2548 ExecStartPre=/etc/resilio-sync/init_user_config.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2554 (rslsync)
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/resilio-sync.service
           └─2554 /usr/bin/rslsync --config /home/daniel/.config/resilio-sync/config.json

Mar 27 18:33:14 daniel-pc systemd[1759]: Starting Resilio Sync service...
Mar 27 18:33:14 daniel-pc systemd[1759]: resilio-sync.service: Failed to read PID from file /home/daniel/.config/resilio-sync/sync.pid: Invalid argument
Mar 27 18:33:14 daniel-pc systemd[1759]: Started Resilio Sync service.
```

I assume there is some additional information required, but I am unable to find anything of use. The logfile in ~/.config only lists my successful manual start, nothing about the failed start.

The resilio-sync.service on my system:

```
[Unit]
Description=Resilio Sync service
Documentation=http://help.getsync.com/
After=network.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=on-failure
PIDFile=%h/.config/resilio-sync/sync.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rslsync --config %h/.config/resilio-sync/config.json
ExecStartPre=/etc/resilio-sync/init_user_config.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: Did you check the logs at `journalctl --user daniel --user-unit=resilio-sync` ?

Comment: @MarkStosberg: Did not know about that command, I get:
`No journal files were found.
Failed to add match 'daniel': Invalid argument`

Comment: When I run `journalctl --user --user-unit=resilio-sync` instead it returns `No journal files were found.
-- No entries --`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I went through all commands again and found my error. I ran both commands from the tutorial:

```
systemctl --user enable resilio-sync
```

and

```
systemctl enable resilio-sync
```

Was resolved running

```
systemctl --user disable resilio-sync
systemctl disable resilio-sync
systemctl --user enable resilio-sync
```

Answer (score 0):

After having installed Resilio in my Raspberry Pi 3 I have run into the same problem, but fortunately I have found the solution (and I hope it works for you). I would like to share my experience with you.

At first I tried the 5 options shown on the following web page, none of which worked.

https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/

I remembered that installing conky, the same stuff had happened to me and it was solved thanks to the information in this post.(Thank you, Novaspirit!)

https://www.novaspirit.com/2017/02/23/desktop-widget-raspberry-pi-using-conky/

Using the terminal (typically by pressing Ctrl+Alt+t), open a new file with your favorite text editor:

```
sudo gedit /usr/bin/resilio.sh
```

Copy, paste the following text and then save it and you can close the editor:

```
#!/bin/sh
systemctl --user start resilio-sync
exit 0
```

Go back to the terminal and make the newly created file executable by typing:

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/bin/resilio.sh
```

Now create a new file "resilio.desktop" that will run when the PC starts up.

```
sudo gedit /etc/xdg/autostart/resilio.desktop
```

Copy and paste the following text:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=resilio
Type=Application
Exec=sh /usr/bin/resilio.sh
Terminal=false
Comment=RESILIO.
Categories = Utility;
```

You can now close the text editor.

That is all.

I hope this is also hepful for you, both in RPi systems and other linux distributions.